# how to groupby or aggregate Pandas dataframe without an operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a somewhat specific situation involving a Pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['group1','group1','group1'], 'value1':[0,0,0],'value2':['A','B','C']})
```

Here, the 0 values can be interpreted as 'blank' or NaN for the entire column.

All I want to do is "group by" the 'col1' value which in this case is only 'group1' and obtain a dataframe that has:

- one value under 'col1' ('group1')
- one value under 'value1' (0)
- 3 values under 'value2' ('A','B','C')

Comment: Is this what you want? `df.groupby(['col1', 'value1'], as_index=False).agg(list)  `

Comment: Could you actually share how exactly the desired output should look like?

Comment: @laszlopanaflex if you have 3 rows for `A`, `B`, and `C` under the `value2` column, then you will need to have 3 rows for the whole dataframe, under the other columns too. It's not clear what you're asking at the moment, I think it would be very helpful if you included a picture/code of what your desired output would be.

Comment: Are you trying to just set the index? `df.set_index(['col1', 'value1'], append=True).reorder_levels([1, 2, 0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with `set`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['group1','group1','group1'], 'value1':[0,0,0],'value2':['A','B','C']})
print(df.groupby('col1').agg(set).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
     col1 value1     value2
0  group1    {0}  {A, C, B}
```

---

Or, if you want to keep it as a list, you could try this:

```
print(df.groupby('col1').agg(set).applymap(list).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
     col1 value1     value2
0  group1    [0]  ['A', 'C', 'B']
```

---

Also, if you want to keep the unique number without a list, you could try:

```
print(df.groupby('col1').agg(lambda x: x[0] if len(set(x))==1 else list(x)).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
     col1  value1     value2
0  group1       0  [A, B, C]
```

Comment: This works because there's a unique value in `col1` so `groupby` works fine, however it will fail to work if there were to exist a `group2` or a non-unique value in `col1` I think.

Comment: You mean a dataframe like this: `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['group1','group1','group1','group2','group2','group2'], 'value1':[0,0,0,1,2,2],'value2':['A','B','C','A','B','C']})` @CeliusStingher? or you mean like if there is a non-unique value different to 0, then it will make the set function?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but it gets the job done for the OP, so +1 from me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea, a bit over-complicated, but it gets the job done:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['group1','group1','group1'], 'value1':[0,0,0],'value2':['A','B','C']})
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame({x:str(list(set(df[x].values.tolist()))) for x in df},index=[0])
```

Output:

```
         col1 value1           value2
0  ['group1']    [0]  ['C', 'B', 'A']
```

However, using `str` to force everything to be in a single line and avoid an Index Error because of having arrays of different lengths, can be undone with `ast.literal_eval()`, returning the values to lists instead of strings:

```
df_grouped = df_grouped.T
df_grouped = df_grouped[0].map(lambda x:ast.literal_eval(x)).to_frame().T
```

Returning finally:

```
       col1 value1     value2
0  [group1]    [0]  [C, B, A]
```

But with the correct type for the values (lists):

```
print(type(df_grouped.loc[0,'col1']))
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
```